# call a PHP function once every certain time

Tags: php, curl

In a part of the website I send a call to a function that brings me an identification of authorization but I want that only be done with a time each time, in the place that every time that enters the card of the purchase

How could I do it?

I am in an integration in paypal

in a file called functions.php
I have the function get_access_token

```
function get_access_token($url, $postdata) {
    global $clientId, $secret;
    $curl = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST,'TLSv1');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId . ":" . $secret);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
    # curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    $response = curl_exec( $curl );
    if (empty($response)) {
        // some kind of an error happened
        die(curl_error($curl));
        curl_close($curl); // close cURL handler
    } else {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl); // close cURL handler
        if($info['http_code'] != 200 && $info['http_code'] != 201 ) {
            echo "Received error: " . $info['http_code']. "\n";
            echo "Raw response:".$response."\n";
            die();
        }
    }
    // Convert the result from JSON format to a PHP array 
    $jsonResponse = json_decode( $response );
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $jsonResponse->access_token;
    return $jsonResponse->access_token;
}
```

in another file I call the function
//GET ACCESS TOKEN

```
$url = $host.'/v1/oauth2/token'; 
$postArgs = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
$access_token= get_access_token($url,$postArgs);
```

the situation is that each time a decline is made or the page is refreshed, a new call is made

the part of

```
$access_token= get_access_token($url,$postArgs);
```

It should only be run once every 6 hours

thanks for your contributions

Comment: I think you need to explain your issue a bit clearer

Comment: Could you explain your problem a bit more ? do i understood you right that you want a extended login ? you want that the user also needs to transfer money to you ?

Comment: add new data, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can save the received data to the user-session. So you can read from session and if the entry is older than 6hours you can request the data with curl.

Hope that helps?